# Correctly seeding the InMemoryDatabase on Xunit e2e tests

Tags: c#, automated-tests, e2e-testing, xunit, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 solution with an API project and two separate test projects (one is bare unit tests, other is integration/e2e tests) based on XUnit.

As part of the e2e tests I seed the database with some test data.

Till yesterday, all tests succeeded. Today, I have added a few more tests to my suite and the tests started to behave **inconsistently**:

- Running the full suite locally from Visual Studio succeeded, so I had pushed confidently to Azure DevOps for pipelining
- Running `dotnet test` locally succeedes
- Running the newly added tests (3) individually of course succeeds
- On Azure DevOps, some old tests fail. Interestingly, two consecutive runs yielded the same tests failing. I couldn't run a third execution because I drained all the pipelines budget

Note that **today** Azure DevOps is experiencing an incident in the European area

The errors are different. In one case a REST method invoking a database `COUNT` that is supposed to return 6 returns 0(!), while in another case I have exception

```
System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at Web.TestUtilities.Seeder.Seed(SendGridManagerContext dbContext) in D:\a\1\s\TestUtilities\Seeder.cs:line 27
at Web.WebApplicationFactory.InitDatabase() in D:\a\1\s\WebApplicationFactory.cs:line 164
at TestFixtureBase..ctor(WebApplicationFactory testFactory, ITestOutputHelper outputHelper) in D:\a\1\s\TestFixtureBase.cs:line 27
at Web.Tests.ControllerTests..ctor(WebApplicationFactory testFactory, ITestOutputHelper outputHelper) in D:\a\1\s\Tests\ControllerTests.cs:line 19
```

(I redacted the stack trace a little)

Judging from the relationship between the two errors, I suspect that the method I seed the database is not correct.

### Here is the showdown.

I created a WebApplicationFactory class

```
public class MyWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { protected get; set; }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
        builder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5001")
            .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging
                .ClearProviders()
                .AddXUnit(Output)
                .AddSimpleConsole())
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddLogging(log =>
                    log.AddXUnit(Output ?? throw new Exception(
                        $"{nameof(Output)} stream must be set prior to invoking configuration. It should be done in the test base fixture")));

                services.Remove(services.SingleOrDefault(service =>
                    service.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>)));

                services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("sg_inmemory"));

                services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(.......


                services.AddSingleton(.......
            })
            ;
    }


    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return base.CreateHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(log =>
                log.AddXUnit()
            );
    }

    public HttpClient CreateHttpClientAuthenticatedUsingMicrosoftOidc()
    {

    }

    public async Task<HttpClient> CreateHttpClientAuthenticatedUsingPrivateOidcAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {

    }

    public void InitDatabase()
    {
        using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
        using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        dbContext.Seed(); //Extension method defined elsewhere
    }

    public void DestroyDatabase()
    {
        using var scope = Services.CreateScope();
        using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```

To really **seed** the database I created my own extension method

```
    public static void Seed(this MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        using var tx = new TransactionScope();

        dbContext.MyEntity.AddRange(GetSeedData());
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        tx.Complete();
    }
```

And to invoke DB init/destroy cycle on testing I leverage constructor and disposer

```
public class ControllerTests : TestFixtureBase
{
    public ControllerTests(MyWebApplicationFactory testFactory, ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
        : base(testFactory, outputHelper)
    {
    }
    // Let's talk about test code later
}
```

This class inherits from the same fixture

```
public abstract class TestFixtureBase : IClassFixture<MyWebApplicationFactory>, IDisposable
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource => Debugger.IsAttached
        ? new CancellationTokenSource()
        : new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

    protected MtWebApplicationFactory TestFactory { get; }
    protected HttpClient PublicHttpClient => TestFactory.CreateClient();
    protected CancellationToken CancellationToken => _cancellationTokenSource.Token;

    protected TestFixtureBase(MyWebApplicationFactory testFactory,
        ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
    {
        TestFactory = testFactory;
        TestFactory.Output = outputHelper;
        TestFactory.InitDatabase();
    }


    ~TestFixtureBase() => Dispose(false);


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }


    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            TestFactory.DestroyDatabase();
            PublicHttpClient.Dispose();
            _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Newly added tests resemble existing tests. **Please note that** the tests that are failing are old tests that passed before my push, and I only **added** functionality

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestStatistics_ReturnsNull() // tests that REST controller returns empty JSON array []
    {
        var client = TestFactory.CreateHttpClientAuthenticatedUsingMicrosoftOidc();
        var message = await client.GetAsync(
            "/api/v1/secure/Controller/statistics/?Environment.IsNull=true",
            CancellationToken); //shall return empty

        message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result =
            await message.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<StatisticsDTO>>(
                cancellationToken: CancellationToken);

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Empty(result);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCount_NoFilter()
    {
        var client = TestFactory.CreateHttpClientAuthenticatedUsingMicrosoftOidc();
        var message = await client.GetAsync("/api/v1/secure/Controller/count",
            CancellationToken);

        message.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var result = await message.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<int>();

        int expected = Seeder.GetSeedData().Count(); //The seeder generates 6 mock records today

        Assert.Equal(expected, result); //Worked till last push
    }
```

## My investigation and question

I suspect that due to the asynchronicity there could be some point where the test runs exactly after another disposing test has cleared the database, and for the duplicate key error I am having a hard time understanding it.

It is my educated guess that I am doing something wrong in seeding the database.

Currently my requirement is that the REST application is started with some mocked records ready in its in-memory database. While the database is in memory and is ephemeral, I tried to do the educated exercise to clear up the databse as this code will be part of examples to share with fellow developer-students in order to teach them correct patterns. Please allow me to insist on *clearing* an in memory database.

And finally, there is nothing special in the pipeline code (I did `dotnet restore` in the beginning)

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Execute tests"
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: |
      *Tests/*.csproj
    arguments: '--no-restore'
```

Comment: Did you added new tests to new test class? Did you try to force every fixture to use different database by having unique database name: `options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())`?

Comment: Using a unique database name had a devastating effect on existing assertions. I added new tests to the old test class that was up and running. Good clue.

Comment: By the way, we were just forced to purchase one parallel Azure DevOps job, and at the third run the tests succeeded on DevOps. Smells like flaky testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the solution was to use an *always-different* database identifier on every test.

According to @Fabio's comment, I'd have to generate a database name every time the lambda expression `services.AddDbContext<SendGridManagerContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(???));` is invoked, but this happens to be invoked often as the object has a [prototype scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#prototype) (**yes**, the article is about Spring for Java, but same principle applies).

In fact, in that case the guid is regenerated every time the DbContext is instantiated.

Solution? Generate a random id, but make it fixed for the whole duration of the test.

The correct place is inside the Test Factory class

```
public class MyWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { protected get; set; }
    private readonly string dataContextName = $"myCtx_{Guid.NewGuid()}"; //Even plain Guid is ok, as soon as it's unique

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
        builder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5001")
            .ConfigureLogging(...)
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {   
                services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(dataContextName));
            })
            ;
    }

}
```